# How make Dynamic Linearlayouts with five imageviews with it

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic

Hi I'm working with this for two days already.

Basically I want to achieve this design(please see the one encircled in red):

**http://tinypic.com/r/dy52k0/8**

I want my xml layout for this one to be dynamic, whatever the screen size of the mobile is, it will just expand or shrink(in short it will retain the design).

Unfortunately I'm having a hard time for this now. This is my code's outcome:

**http://tinypic.com/r/29uo8d4/8**

and here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- start - Main Buttons for Main Pages -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <!-- start - For Glomp Image -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#585f6b"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10sp"
                android:paddingRight="10sp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="170sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/glomp_logo_for_login" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!-- end - For Glomp Image -->


            <!-- start - For 4 Menu Buttons -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="0sp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgV_main_menu_points"
                        android:layout_width="80sp"
                        android:layout_height="80sp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/glomped" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgV_main_menu_glomped"
                        android:layout_width="80sp"
                        android:layout_height="80sp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/friends" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgV_main_menu_points"
                        android:layout_width="80sp"
                        android:layout_height="80sp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgV_main_menu_points"
                        android:layout_width="80sp"
                        android:layout_height="80sp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/points" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- end - For 4 Menu Buttons -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- end - Main Buttons for Main Pages -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: you are making too much complex UI

Comment: your req is like first row glomp repeat multiple time Right ?

Comment: I have given rep if it will helpful for you please accept ans

Comment: as per the @kanak ans placed all the images in diff drawable folder with different size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic layouts, your imageviews need to set width as `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and not in units as you have done.

You will need images of different sizes to support different screen sizes and resolutions and place them in specific folders in `res/drawable` like -

```
MyProject/res/
drawable-xhdpi/
    awesomeimage.png
drawable-hdpi/
    awesomeimage.png
drawable-mdpi/
    awesomeimage.png
drawable-ldpi/
    awesomeimage.png
```

Also you may have different rs/layout folders.

Please see: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will helpful for you because just created same as your view. I will work for all devices

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF00FF" >
<!-- this is glomp -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <!-- this is glomp G -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#31B404" />
         <!-- this is menu-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#2A120A" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
         <!-- this is friends-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FF00" />
         <!-- this is point-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i tried it already and kanak gave me the answer that i am looking for

Comment: Nice rog I hope it is useful view for every devices